# Using Input Box to Post onto Twitter

Tags: api, forms, twitter

Is it possible to post onto Twitter using the sharing URL, for example:

http://twitter.com/home?status=My Status Update

But, instead of creating a link for a user to click, I want to have an input box that will post the content of the input box as the status.  So, whatever the user types into the input box would replace My Status Update.

I'm thinking there should be a way to use the form to post onto this URL hxxp://twitter.com/home?status=XXXX where XXXX is the input value.  Is this possible?

**UPDATE:  I realize I described this wrong - it doesn't have to ACTUALLY POST the status, it can take them to Twitter, ask them to logged in (if not, skip), and then put the status update inside the Tweet Box and require the user to press Tweet to send it**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, Twitter require the status to be sent from it's interface.

You can provide the user an option to send status from your site only with twitter application and only after the user authorized your application to sends twits in his account.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  The Sharing URL works (http://www.twitter.com/home/status=BLAHBLAHBLAH), but I guess thats the only way to do it?

Comment: The sharing URL forward the user to his profile with the message, not submitting it for him. The logic is quite simple: to avoid spam. Think about spammers sites - They would exploit it wherever they can.

Comment: Thats OK, it doesn't have to post it for them, just bring them to the page where they can first login and next press "Tweet" themselves.  That would be OK for me.

Comment: That doesnt do anything, but I think you meant twitter.com/home/status=BLAHBLAHBLAH  

Which I know how to do, I want to know if it can be populated through a form

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the solution to this may be more complicated then you think.

Twitter recently switched to full OAuth authentication to interact with their api and to post status updates etc.

In short, to do what you suggest above will require your visitors to log in.

To simplify this, on my websites I use the [Official Twitter Tweet Button](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton) because I feel that my visitors will trust it the most and will enter in their username/pass without worry.

The [Official Twitter Tweet Button](http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton) page has a builder where you can select various options to change the look and content of the tweet itself.

Be sure to checkout the full documentation for the [advanced usage examples](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button#Examples) and the full reference of [properties that can be used with the javascript tweet button](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_button#properties-which-can-be-used-by-the-javascript-tweet-button)

p.s.

On my site I registered for an app so I could include the following js file:

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=MY-APP-ID&amp;v=1"></script>
```

And my links look something like this:

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://mydomain.com/url-to-post" data-text="Text that will actually be tweeted" data-count="horizontal" data-via="mytwitteraccount">Tweet</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info.  I realize I described this wrong - it doesn't have to ACTUALLY POST the status, it can take them to Twitter, ask them to logged in (if not, skip), and then put the status update inside the Tweet Box and require the user to press Tweet to send it.